# How do I position my element at the bottom of my well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The `position:relative` `bottom: 0` is not working for me. I need to position the button at the bottom of my well and in the center. I also have to place the facebook share link in the left side of it, but untill I don't place this right, I cannot plan for the facebook link now.

Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content="";
  $("#click").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("//quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(key) {
     content=key[0].content + "<p>— " + key[0].title + "</p>";
      $("#quote-form").html(content);
      console.log(content);
    });
    
    $("#quote-form").css({"font-family":"lucida console", "font-size": "20px","color":"rgb(255,255,150)"});
     
  });
 
});
```

```css
.position-message{
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right:25%;
  margin-top:10%;

}

.background{
  background-color: rgba(245,245,245,0.2);
  border-radius:10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

#button-shape{
  position:relative;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-left:48%;
  padding-right: 48%;
}

.quote-shape{
  border-radius: 10%;
  width: absolute;
  height: absolute;
}

#page{
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top:2%;
  margin-bottom:2%;
}
#page-background{
  background-image: url(http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/grid_background_line_texture_surface_50781_1920x1080.jpg);
}

#share {
        
        height:30px;
        width: 80px;
        position: 
      }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <Title>Click to get quotes</Title>
</head>

<body id="page-background">
    <div class="well background" id="page">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="quote" class="position-message"> 
             <span><p id="quote-form"></p></span>
            </div>
        <div class="row" id="button-shape">
  <div id="share" class="col">
         <!--<a class="click" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={{fbapp_id}}&link={{link_url}}&message={{share_message|urlencode}}&display=popup&redirect_uri={{link_url}}" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i> Share
        </a> -->
       </div>
    <div class="col">
         <button type="button" id="click button-shape" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is your well container in this code

Comment: just added it now. The button is being positioned at the bottom. But its considering the `top` attribute from its predecessor. Explained: When I click the button, an API is fired and a random quote pops up. Now this top attribute measures the distance between the button and the content, and re positions the button. How do I position the button with respect to the page and not its predecessor?

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237407/6313073) regarding the changes you told me in chat @GauravThantry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have previously set `bottom` to another value, using `position: relative` along with `bottom: 0` is not going to have any visual effect.

There are multiple ways to solve your problem, one of which is using `position: absolute` along with`transform` as shown below:

```css
#button-prop {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Also, in order for the above code to work, you need to set the `position` of the parent to `relative`.

```css
#page {
  position: relative;
}
```

With your current `HTML` structure, however, using traditional ways will fail, because you have nested the button very deep inside the container which has a `padding` set. You need to make some serious changes to your `HTML` structure in order to achieve an optimal result. Most importantly put the `button` as an immediate child to the well, `#page`.

Check out a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gLpgzg2f/) or the following snippet.

**Snippet:**

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */

div.background {
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.quote-shape {
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#page {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 450px;
  max-height: 450px;
}

#page-background {
  background-image: url(http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/grid_background_line_texture_surface_50781_1920x1080.jpg);
}


/*************** MY CODE ***************/

#page {
  position: relative;
  
  /* I change the dimensions to fit in the snippet. */
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

#button-prop {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body id="page-background">
    <div class="well background" id="page">
      <div class="fixed-width">
        <div id="quote" class="position-message">
          <span><p id="quote-form"></p></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="button-prop" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-circle">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Don't use space-separated ids such as `click button-shape`, as you're only making your life more difficult rendering the selector `#click button-shape` invalid, having to use `[id = "click button-shape"]` instead.
2. I have kept only the relevant parts of your code.